# How to monitor a folder with all subfolders and within the subfolder

Tags: vbscript

I am currently working on a vbscript that monitors subfolders. But right now, I want the script to monitor the folders in the subfolder.

For example: the map is 'imports'. And in the import folder there are several folders (subfolders). And in the subfolder there are more several folders, and that is what I want to monitor.

I hope this is clear to understand what I mean.

Example: http://gyazo.com/3f0b7a9d492361fef41fbbe9760a8da1

Example 2: http://gyazo.com/284734da6b70d1b91ac7e3afc4e10918

This is what I have right now:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objExcel, strExcelPath, objSheet, fso, folder, colFolders, objFSO, objFile, objbook, objDoc,                             objShell, rs, f, s, EmailBody, EmailAttachments, objWorkbook, strFile, IntRow, objRange, x,       objWorksheet,wbc, SaveChanges, objSubFolder, objFrigolanda, foldername, moddate,folders, Frigolanda
Const adVarChar = 200 
Const adDate = 7 
Const adBigInt = 20
'===== 
'Set objecten
set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject") 
set folder = fso.getfolder("\\netko-sbs\data\imports\") 
Set colFolders = folder.SubFolders
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("\\netko-sbs\data\Imports\output.txt", True)
'===== 
' Check if file exists.
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If (objFSO.FileExists(strFile) = True) Then
   objFSO.DeleteFile(strFile)
End If
'===== 
'create a custom disconnected recordset 
'with fields for filename, last modified date, and size. 
'===== 
 set rs = createobject("ador.recordset") 
 rs.fields.append "foldername",adVarChar,255 
 rs.fields.append "moddate",adDate 
'rs.fields.append "filesize",adBigInt 
'====
'Excel
'Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
 Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open _
   ("\\netko-sbs\Data\Imports\output.xlsx") 'Opslaan als..
 objExcel.Visible = True  'toon excel
 objExcel.DisplayAlerts = FALSE 'Foutmeldingen uitschakelen
 objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "foldernaam" 'cellen naam geven
 objExcel.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Laatste import" 'cellen naam geven

 x = 2 'set de juiste rij in excel
 '===== 
 'opening without any connection info makes 
 'it "disconnected". 
 '=====  
 rs.open 
'===== 
'load it with file name, date, etc. 
'===== 
for each frigolanda in folder.SubFolders
if frigolanda = "frigolanda" then
set folderfrigo = fso.getfolder ("\\netko-sbs\data\imports\Frigolanda\")
set colFolders = folder.SubFolders
    end if
next
For each 



for each f in folder.SubFolders     
 rs.addnew array("foldername","moddate"), _ 
           array(f.name,f.datelastmodified) 
 rs.update 
 next 
s = "Sortering van Oud naar Nieuw:" & vbcrlf  _ 
  & "=============================" & vbcrlf 
if not (rs.bof and rs.eof) then 
   rs.sort = "moddate asc" 
   rs.movefirst 
   do until rs.eof 
  s = s & rs("foldername") & ";" _ 
      & rs("moddate") & vbcrlf 
    objExcel.Cells(x, 1).Value = _
        rs.Fields("foldername").Value 
    objExcel.Cells(x, 2).Value = _
        rs.Fields("moddate").Value 
        x = x + 1
    rs.movenext 
 loop 
end if 

objFile.WriteLine s 'Schrijf waarden naar Excel
Set rs = nothing 'Gooi RS leeg 
Set folder = nothing 'Object leegmaken
set fso = nothing 'Object leegmaken

Set objRange = objExcel.Range("A1") 'Selecteer actieve cell
objRange.Activate 'Activeer cell

Set objRange = objExcel.ActiveCell.EntireColumn
objRange.Autofit() 'Set grootte van kolom

Set objRange = objExcel.Range("B1") 'Selecteer actieve cell
objRange.Activate 'Activeer cell

Set objRange = objExcel.ActiveCell.EntireColumn
objRange.Autofit() 'Set grootte van kolom


ObjWorkbook.SaveAs "\\netko-sbs\Data\Imports\output.xlsx" 'Excel bestand opslaan
'objExcel.Quit 'Excel afsluiten als nodig is.
```

Comment: What do you want to be notified of? When a file is created/modified/deleted within a subfolder? Or when a subfolder is created/deleted?

Comment: When a folder is last modified. That is what i'm aiming for.

Comment: How is a folder "modified"? If the folder name changes? If it has files added, removed, or changed? If it has subfolders added or removed? Just trying to understand what type of "modification" you want to be notified about.

Comment: When a file has been added. that is basically it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMI and the `InstanceCreationEvent` class to be notified when a file or folder is created. [Here's a column from The Scripting Guy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/04/21/how-can-i-monitor-a-folder-for-the-creation-of-new-subfolders.aspx) about this topic. It discusses how to be notified of *subfolders* being created, not files, but the idea is the same. Unforunately, you can only monitor a single folder, not a folder hierarchy.

So, apart from using third-party tools, the only solution I can think of is the iterate the folder structure and store your list of files in a dictionary. Then, poll the folder at some interval to see if any changes occurred.

For example:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' Initialize the file list...
DoFolder "\\netko-sbs\data\imports", True

' Now poll the folder every 10 seconds, looking for new files...
Do
    WScript.Sleep 10000
    DoFolder "\\netko-sbs\data\imports", False
Loop

' Recursive function...
Sub DoFolder(strFolder, bFirstTime)

    ' Add each file to our dictionary...
    For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder).Files

        If bFirstTime Then

            ' Initializing. Just add every file we find...
            d.Add objFile.Path, ""

        Else

            ' Polling. Report any new files...
            If Not d.Exists(objFile.Path) Then

                ' New file found! Do something with it.

            End If

        End If

    Next

    ' Recursively check each subfolder...
    For Each objFolder In objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder).SubFolders
        DoFolder objFolder.Path
    Next

End Sub
```

This runs once to build a list of files in your folder hierarchy. Then, you can run it again after a period of time to check for any *new* files.

Comment: This is very helpful. And what about specific subfolders?. How do you exclude them?

Comment: I just spoke with my boss and he told me that this looks good but is not exactly what we are trying to accomplish. I will make a new post with the full detail.